# The best constant of Poincare inequality can be determined by eigenvalue of Laplace operator

Tags: sobolev-spaces, calculus-of-variations

Given $\Omega\subset \mathbb R^N$ be open bounded and smooth boundary. Then for $u\in H_0^1(\Omega)$ we have well-known Poincare inequality 
$$ \int_\Omega \lvert u\lvert^2dx\leq C\int_\Omega \lvert\nabla u\lvert^2dx \tag 1$$

I'm interested in finding the best constant $C$ here. Re-write $(1)$, we have 
$$ \frac{1}{C}\leq \frac{\int_\Omega \lvert\nabla u\lvert^2dx}{ \int_\Omega \lvert u\lvert^2dx} $$
and hence we only need to find
$$ \inf_{u\in H_0^1(\Omega)} \int_\Omega \lvert\nabla u\lvert^2dx:=\alpha$$
over the admissible set $M:=\{u\in H_0^1(\Omega)\,\|u\|_{L^2(\Omega)}=1\}$. Then by [Rayleigh Quotient theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1088029/using-direct-method-to-prove-rayleigh-quotient-theorem) we have $\alpha=\lambda_1$ where $\lambda_1$ is the first eigenvalue of laplace operator $-\Delta $.

Hence the best constant of Poincare inequality is just $1/\lambda_1$? Am I correct?

I think this problem has been well studied. So if you know where I can find a good reference, please kindly direct me there. Thank you!

Comment: Searching "Rayleigh quotient, eigenfunction, Laplacian" brings up quite a few results, such as [these lecture notes](http://web.stanford.edu/class/math220b/handouts/eigenvalues.pdf) with a proof of the above, and a more general result.

Comment: @Behaviour Thank you for reference. I'll check it out!