# Best possible constant for Poincare inequality.

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

Consider Poincare inequality in the form of:
$|u|_{0,\Omega} \leq C|u|_{1,\Omega} \text{ for every } u\in H^1_0(\Omega),$
where $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is a bounded open set. Find the best possible value of $C$.

Any type of help will be appriciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the question? What is the precise definition of your norm?

Answer (score 1):

Finding the best constant for Poincare inequality (or korn's inequality) is a long standing problem. Unfortunately, there is no general answer. (not I am known of). However, for some specially domains, there is something you can do.

For example, if $\Omega$ is a ball, then the best constant is the radius of the ball(or something similar). I would suggest you to read this [book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0821847686), chapter 12.2. Inside you could find more informations, for example ,the poincare for star-sharped domains, and more.

Comment: But you answered it here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1088051/the-best-constant-of-poincare-inequality-can-be-determined-by-eigenvalue-of-lapl?rq=1